# Regular expression - get e-mail and data

Tags: php, regex, email

I have a error of my program to send emails. Now i have the files where are exported e-mail's.
Searching of regular expression, what can get me only the email in Return-Path.

```
  Some content
  Return-Path: <email@domain.com>
  Some content
```

Comment: so u want a regex to match an email address ?

Comment: yes, @bytehamster solved problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should do what you want:

```
(?=Return-Path:)([^\n]*)<([^>]*)>
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/oL9kE8/2

Comment: Thank You - work `/(?=Return-Path:)([^\\n]*)<([^>]*)>/`